# Delphi - Excel - Working with Hyperlinks

Tags: excel, delphi, hyperlink, excel-formula

Delphi Seattle, Excel 2013.  I am writing an application which creates a spreadsheet.  One column of the spreadsheet will be a hyperlink to a search in LinkedIn.  I create my URL with the search parameters.  If I call the URL at this point, via ShellExecute, it works.  I now insert my hyperlink into Excel.  If I click on the cell, I get a different page.  For example... create a URL which searches on IBM.  Perform a ShellExecute.... LinkedIn shows IBM contacts. Insert that same URL into a cell in the spreadsheet, then click on the cell.  The web browser shows a page with the URL of https://www.linkedin.com/?trk=login_reg_redirect.  It does not matter if I am already logged into LinkedIn or not. I have tried this in both Delphi and in pure Excel.  If I add this as a formula, I get the same behavior (aka wrong page). The formula is

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?company=IBM","IBM")
```

If I copy and paste the URL into a browser, I get the proper IBM page.  My first thought was that LinkedIn did not allow/prevented other apps from calling their pages directly, yet I create an application (via Delphi) which opens a browser page with the IBM URL, and it works.

Here is sample Delphi code to show the problem.  Any thoughts welcome...

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  url: string;
  oExcel: ExcelApplication;
  RawDataSheet: _Worksheet;
begin
  // The first two lines open a valid search page on LinkedIn showing IBM contacts
  URL := 'https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?company=IBM';
  ShellExecute(self.WindowHandle, 'open', PChar(url), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

  oExcel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application') as ExcelApplication;
  oExcel.Visible[LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT] := True;

 // Add a New Workbook, with a single sheet
  oExcel.Workbooks.Add(EmptyParam, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT);

 // Get the handle to the active Sheet, and insert some dummy data
  RawDataSheet := oExcel.ActiveSheet as _Worksheet;

  // Add the Hyperlink, appears to work but takes me to wrong page
  RawDataSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(RawDataSheet.Range['A1', 'A1'], Url, EmptyParam, 'Attempt Contact lookup in LinkedIn', 'IBM');
  // Show the hyperlink text in a different cell
  RawDataSheet.Range['A2', 'A2'].Value2 := Url;

   // Verify the right URL was saved to the cell.  It appears so...
  ShowMessage(RawDataSheet.Range['A1', 'A1'].Hyperlinks[1].Address);

end;
```

The resulting LinkedIn page [login_reg_redirect] appears to be showing that the way Excel is opening a webpage is different than Delphi does with a ShellExecute.

Comment: I don't know the answer so I won't pretend that I do, but my guess is that when you use ShellExecute it operates in the same space, using the same port, as if you were working directly in your browser. Excel is probably operating in a different space and therefore using a different port which LinkedIn detects and redirects you to the login page. I think you will need to log in from Excel for this to work.

Comment: @DSM - That was what I was wondering, but I am hesitant... Reasoning:  I manually open a browser, log in to LinkedIn.  I then go to my spreadsheet, and click the hyperlink cell.  I then get another tab in the same browser opened to LinkedIn, but with the login_redirect URL showing...and my picture at the top of the new page, so it knows who I am...

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it is not quite the same. You are opening Excel as an OLE object, which means it runs in its own space - almost as if a second user were using it. I don't know if you can set security credentials up to make it operate as if it were you - that is way out of my league I'm afraid. To prove it, save the Excel file you generate, open it manually and try clicking on the links. My bet would be that they will work.

Comment: @Dsm - Good thought, but when I save, close and reopen, I get the same behavior.  I have even written the raw URL to another cell.  If I click on that, go to the end (so Excel recognizes it as a URL), then double-click... I get the new tab in my browser, it shows my picture (so I am logged in) but the URL is back to login-redir.

Comment: Yes you at right. In fact if you type the hyperlink in manually (nothing to do with Delphi) you get the same action. It must be to do with LinkedIn as well. If you can't do it manually, you can't do it with Delphi, so there is no problem with your code clearly. I wonder if it is anything to do with it opening in a new tab every time, but I can't see why.

Comment: Must be to do with cookies too, I imagine.

Comment: I find (via google) the answer to your question (but not your problem, sadly) here http://superuser.com/questions/444984/excel-hyperlink-not-redirecting-properly-bug.